# Show the selected value of a SpinButton on a label

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a UserForm with a SpinButton on it. The user selects a value and when done, clicks OK (to pass the selected value to another procedure).

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Now, **how do I display the selected value in the SpinButton** on a Label or something else that shows the user which value she selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `SpinButton1_Change` event. This will update the label realtime when the you click the spinbutton up/down arrow.

In the userform code area, simply paste this code

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    Label1.Caption = SpinButton1.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your SpinButton in the `UserForm_Initialize` and add a line in `SpinButton_Change` to update the Label :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With SpinButton1
        .Min = 0 'Min Value
        .Max = 100 'Max Value

        'Specify the value of the change when the spin button is clicked
        .SmallChange = 5 '(Default = 1)
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    Label1.Caption = SpinButton1.Value
End Sub
```